# Github pull request without old commits

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have forked project at github. I make one commit and pull request it. This commit was approved. Then i make second commit and pull request it too. But in pull request there were 2 commits: my second commit and old commit which was approved. How can i sync my repository and main repository?

Comment: People could provide a more comprehensive answer here if you were to add links to your github repository and the upstream github repository.  (I understand if you're not happy to, of course.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Merge back from the upstream repository, or create the new pull request on a new branch.

Or rebase on top of upstream:

```
git remote add upstream (url-for-upstream-repository)
git fetch upstream
git rebase upstream/master
git push -f origin
(do new pull request on website)
```

Comment: If you push -f to the existing branch name, Github will see the branch was updated.  If it doesn't, you could git push origin :branch_name, then git push origin branch_name and the pull request would be updated.

Comment: Adam, would you be willing to explain what each of those lines do?

Comment: add the remote, fetch info about the remote, rebase the remote changes into current branch, then push forced -f; --force : Usually, the command refuses to update a remote ref that is not an ancestor of the local ref used to overwrite it. This flag disables the check. This can cause the remote repository to lose commits; use it with care.