# How to do a pull request in GitHub with only the latest commit in the master branch of my forked repository

Tags: git, github, branch, fork, pull-request

I forked a repository on github. I made some changes and did a pull request.

Now I made some other changes and want to do a new pull request, but on the preview screen before doing the pull request it shows the old commits too (the ones that were already accepted).

How do I select only the latest commit in the master branch of my forked repository so that I can do a pull request with only that commit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Github pull request without old commits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415560/github-pull-request-without-old-commits)

Comment: Like the answer found by Talljoe says, either merge the upstream master to your branch or rebase your master on top of the upstream master.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This answer from a coworker fixed my problem:

```
git checkout -b NEW_BRANCH_NAME LAST_COMMIT_NAME_BEFORE_THE_ONE_WANTED
git cherry-pick COMMIT_NAME_WANTED
git push origin NEW_BRANCH_NAME
```

Then on GitHub you can do a pull request for the new branch you created.

**UPDATE**

I asked and answered this question when I first started working with git. Now that I know more about it, I'd like to expand this answer.

When working with a fork you probably want to keep it updated with respect to the original repo. So these would be the steps I would follow today:

```
git remote add upstream GIT_URL_OF_THE_ORIGINAL_REPO
```

Now you have a reference called `upstream` which points to that repo. By default you should also have another one called `origin` which would point to your fork in this case. `upstream` and `origin` is just how people usually name these references, but you can use whatever name you want.

Now you need to get the latest changes:

```
git fetch upstream
```

Then if you want to update your fork with changes from `upstream` you'd do this:

```
git checkout master //checkout your master branch
git merge upstream/master //merge changes from the master branch in upstream into the branch you checked out (master)
git push origin master //if you want to push your updated master to your remote fork
```

**Now, to answer the original question, what I would do today if I wanted to submit a new PR, would be**:

```
git fetch upstream //get the latest changes from the original repo
git checkout -b my_new_feature upstream/master //create a new branch, starting from the master in the original repo
git cherry-pick WHATEVER_COMMIT_I_WANT //select the commit I want and add it to this new branch
git push origin my_new_feature //push a new branch to my fork
```

Then I would request a new PR for the `my_new_feature` branch.

You can replace `git cherry-pick WHATEVER_COMMIT_I_WANT` with just modifying/adding a file and then doing `git add FILENAME`, `git commit -m "Fixing some stuff"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was searching for this since a lot of time.

Answer (score 4):

You could probably be to put the commits in a separate branch (branching before the first set of commits), assuming they're unrelated to the first commits.  Then the separate branch can be the target of the pull request and will only include your second set of commits.