# How to create multiple PRs for specific set of commits

Tags: git, github, version-control, pull-request

I am actually contributing to one of the Material Design code repository. There are a certain set of features that is planned for next release.

I have currently implemented one feature and created a PR(say PR1) and 3 commits of that feature are pushed. They are visible under that **PR1**. The PR1 is still in `OPEN` state.

I have already implemented certain other feature with 8 commits. But, when I click on the button **"Create New PR"**, all I see is my **PR1**.

Here is what happens when I click on **"Create New PR"**-

[image]

Problem is-

1. If I push the 8 commits, it goes under PR1.
2. Unable to create a new PR for 8 commits.

How do I do it? This has been a long problem. And now I have to ask.

**Why new PR?** That's because, it becomes easier to review and each feature with 1 PR would be cleaner approach.

I have already been through - [Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102297/how-do-i-clean-up-my-github-fork-so-i-can-make-clean-pull-requests), [Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256021/send-a-pull-request-on-github-for-only-latest-commit), [Question3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561161/how-to-do-a-pull-request-in-github-with-only-the-latest-commit-in-the-master-bra?lq=1) and few more...

With not much help. It's just that I am spamming the repo with commits & then resetting head forcefully to delete it :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GitHub's pull requests can be [updated by pushing new commits the existing branch](https://github.com/github/hub/issues/198). This is a deliberate design decision allowing PRs to be incrementally improved.

The solution is to push the changes you wish to be considered separately to a different branch and to open a new PR from that branch.

Comment: Does this mean, I create a new branch on my Fork, then push it to the master of the Main Repo? Each new branch for every new feature I want to commit in parallel?

Comment: @bozzmob, you need to push to a new branch on GitHub. One GitHub branch per Pull Request.