# Old commits showing up in new Pull Request?

Tags: git, version-control, pull-request

I have done some work on branch A, made several commits, pushed those commits, and made a pull request into B which has gotten approved, so I completed the merge. Now the problem is that I am making more commits & pushes on branch A so that I can make another pull request, but the old several commits from before are still there kind of polluting the new Pull Request, along with the new ones..

It's not really a problem, it just looks bad to the approving programmer (he has to ignore the first 7 commits and just look at the last 2 for example). Is there a way to get rid of these old commits from the new pull request? I tried making a new branch at the head of A, then deleting that old A (both locally and remotely), renaming the new A to what old branch A was named; but that still shows those old several commits in the pull request. We use Visual Studio Team Services and git for source control, preferably a gui like SourceTree.

[image: Pull Request]

The two commits at the top are for the new Pull Request; the ones below it are from the last Pull Request. BY merging CK_Dev into master, I mean merging A into B. Sorry for the inelegance, I'm still blurry on git..

Comment: Is there any chance you can give us a link to the pull request in question? It sounds like you probably need to rebase your work on top of the target branch, but it's hard to say without details.

Comment: Didn't you use "squash merge" to merge the first PR?

Comment: @larsks Added, thanks

Comment: @max630 I do not remember, but I will make sure to next time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Github pull request without old commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415560/github-pull-request-without-old-commits)

Comment: But it's making me wonder why git does this. Say I branch off of master, then make a commit to that branch, make Pull Request and get it approved. Then I delete that branch locally and remotely. Then when I make a new branch off of master, make a commit to that new branch and do a pull request, it doesn't hold my old commit history. But if I do the same with a branch I created, it keeps the history when I branch off of it, even though it's a new branch. I guess I wasn't expecting the commit history to be kept in the Pull Request when I branched off of a branch.

Comment: @ChrisK So how did you complete the pull request, merged with squash or merge with rebase?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT Neither, see question description.

Comment: @ChrisK based on the screen shot, it can not explain the branches were merged by default manner. On the other side, it mainly caused the PR was completed by **merging with rebase**. So can you provider the graph of commit histories by executing `git fetch` and `gitk --all`?

Comment: @ChrisK Since you laready have a solution  to solve the problem, you can also add the solution in an answer and mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution: I just went through with this pull request and left a note to only look at last x commits. But now I see all that I need to do is: after the pull request approval, make a new branch off of the tip of B (the branch my commits got merged into), delete A remotely and locally, and name that new branch "A". Now I make a commit / push to A and Pull request it to B and only that commit is there. Yay, thanks!