# How to exclude changes form others' commits in my PR?

Tags: git, github, merge, rebase, squash

Initially, I created a new PR for my feature branch which had 2 commits. And my goal was to squash these 2 commits into one.

So on working on my feature branch, I executed the following commands:

```
$ git fetch origin
$ git rebase -i HEAD~2 
A new file opened, I saw a lot of lines. For every line except the 
first, changed “pick” to “squash”. Saved and closed.
Another file opened, I edited the commit messages
$ git rebase origin/master
---> I got conflicts that I resolved
$ git push -u --force-with-lease origin feature_branch_name
```

When, I went to github and pushed "Compare & Pull Request", the new PR contains a lot of changes beside mine.

How could I exclude changes form other people in my PR?

Comment: Are you working on a dedicated branch for your change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Github pull request without old commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415560/github-pull-request-without-old-commits)